# Rename resource file does not change editor part title

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my plugin project, I have a project explorer view where I can rename a config file which in shown in another editor part. The file can be renamed in the explorer with the rename resource dialog but the corresponding the editor tab title does not change. The same problem is described [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t90752.rhtml) and also [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/96905/). Is there a standard way to get the rename functionality working without the creating a custom listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors based on `AbstractTextEditor` (or one of its subclasses such as `TextEditor`) should handle renames through the `FileDocumentProvider` which listens for resource changes.

Other editors need to use an `IResourceChangeListener` to deal with this.

Comment: I have already implemented `IResourceChangeListener` to listen to resourceChanged with event type `IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE` and refresh the project explorer view. How can I use this listener to update the editor title?

Comment: The editor itself must use a similar listener to do all the work necessary to deal with the file name changing.

Comment: Follow up [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170492/iresourcechangelistener-rename-and-set-editorpart-name-dynamically) if you have some time please :)